# Test PHP on MacBook running OSX ML 10.8

Tags: php, apache, webserver, osx-mountain-lion

I'm looking to get started on learning PHP. I was hoping I could get some information on how to test my .php files on my MacBook. I believe I have successfully enabled my "Apache Web Server", as when I visit `http://localhost/` in a web browser I see the message "It works!". My question is what further steps do I need to take to enable my computer to do this? Also once configured where do I place my .php & .html files on my machine? I've read some articles about the /Sites/ folder but I believe it gives me a permission forbidden error.

Comment: Did you try setting permissions?

Comment: how would I go about setting permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend XAMPP. It's what I've used on my Macbook for years now. The link for the OS X version is here:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html

There are great tutorials online through thenewboston here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6ZiPqsBvEQ

Basically once you have it installed, you'll have the folders of your sites stored in htdocs/ folder of the application and once connected to the Apache server you would just go to `http://localhost/my_site` .

Comment: Thank you!! I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could lend a hand. Those tutorials for thenewboston are great for beginners and can really help you get started (they got me started!).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the 
[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) software.